# Not all rows copy from csv into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I have a CSV file contains over 2 mill rows.

When I using the COPY statement in postgresql, it returns a littel over 1 mill rows into postgresql.

I am using the statement below:

```
copy table (

columns[1],
columns[2],
columns[3],
columns[4],
columns[5],
columns[6],
columns[7],
columns[8]
)

from 'C:\Temp\co11700t_bcp\co11700t_bcp.csv' with delimiter ']' quote '"' CSV;
```

I have bulk-copy the data from a cmd-file, and used windows notepad to set encoding to utf-8.